# A recursive algorithm to find every possible sum given an integer array?

Tags: java, recursion

So given an array for example **[3, 5, 7, 2]** I want to use recursion to give me all the possible combinations of sums, `for example: 3, 5, 7, 2, 8(3+5),10(3+7),5(3+5)... 15(3+5+7)` etc. I'm not exactly sure how to go about this using java.

Answer (score 3):

You have two choice with each number in the array.

1. Use the number
2. Don't use the number

   ```
   void foo(int[] array, int start, int sum) {
       if(array.length == start) return;
       int val = sum + array[start];
       //print val;
       foo(array, start + 1, val); //use the number
       foo(array, start + 1, sum); //don't use the number
   }
   ```

the initial call is `foo(a, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

An recursive algorithm for this could work as follows:

All the sums for a list equals the union of:

- The first number plus the sums of the sublist without the first number
- The sums of the sublist without the first number

Eventually your recursive call will hit the stopping condition of an empty list, which has only one sum(zero)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it in pseudo code:

```
getAllPossibleSums(list)
    if(list.length == 1)
        return list[0];
    otherSums = getAllPossibleSums(list[1:end])
    return union(
        otherSums, list[0] + otherSums);
```

Comment: @Confluence: He wants recursion.

Comment: How come you get that word for this code?? Seriously `Dynamic Programming`?? Where is Dynamic here??

Comment: Yes, but at least what I've described here hits the same recursive call a number of times. This is what dynamic programming is. Very similar to recursion, and can naively be implemented with recursion if you like.

Comment: Hmm, it appears there's a much simpler way then what I did, so I've changed mine to pure recursion (no dynamic programming).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    findAllSums(new int[] {3, 5, 7, 2}, 0, 0);
}

static void findAllSums(int[] arrayOfNumbers, int index, int sum) {     
    if (index == arrayOfNumbers.length) {
        System.out.println(sum);
        return;
    }

    findAllSums(arrayOfNumbers, index + 1, sum + arrayOfNumbers[index]);
    findAllSums(arrayOfNumbers, index + 1, sum);
}
```

You have two branches, one in which you add the current number and another in which you don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] A = {3, 5, 7, 2};
    int summation = recursiveSum(A, 0, A.length-1);
    System.out.println(summation);
  }

  static int recursiveSum(int[] Array, int p, int q) {
    int mid = (p+q)/2; //Base case
    if (p>q) return 0; //Base case
    else if (p==q) return Array[p];
    **else
      return  recursiveSum(Array, p, mid) +  recursiveSum(Array, mid + 1, q);**
  }
```

Comment: The problem is to output every possible sum, not just the total.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way ever:

```
private int noOfSet;
```

Add below method:

```
private void checkSum() {
        List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
        input.add(9);
        input.add(8);
        input.add(10);
        input.add(4);
        input.add(5);
        input.add(7);
        input.add(3);

        int targetSum = 15;
        checkSumRecursive(input, targetSum, new ArrayList<Integer>());

    }

    private void checkSumRecursive(List<Integer> remaining, int targetSum, List<Integer> listToSum) {
        // Sum up partial
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x : listToSum) {
            sum += x;
        }

        //Check if sum matched with potential
        if (sum == targetSum) {
            noOfSet++;
            Log.i("Set Count", noOfSet + "");
            for (int value : listToSum) {
                Log.i("Value", value + "");
            }
        }

        //Check sum passed
        if (sum >= targetSum)
            return;

        //Iterate each input character
        for (int i = 0; i < remaining.size(); i++) {
            // Build list of remaining items to iterate
            List<Integer> newRemaining = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = i + 1; j < remaining.size(); j++)
                newRemaining.add(remaining.get(j));

            // Update partial list
            List<Integer> newListToSum = new ArrayList<>(listToSum);
            int currentItem = remaining.get(i);
            newListToSum.add(currentItem);
            checkSumRecursive(newRemaining, targetSum, newListToSum);
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.